# Intellij Idea - what configuration to use for Scala

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, configuration

I am having trouble running Scala on *Intellij Idea*.

I have a Scala Object (basic `HelloWorld`), but I am unable to run it (the run button is grayed out).

I know I need to add a configuration before running, but which one should I choose? *Intellij Idea* offers templates like ScalaTest and Scala REPL, but I have no knowledge on the differences of these or what options I should set on them, or if should use either of them. I couldn't find tutorials on this either.

[image]

Comment: Hi, the code was: object HelloWorld extends App{ println("Hello World!") }
The problem solved when I recreated the object as "pme" told me, and rewrote the code instead of copying the file to the new project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is maybe to create a new Project and then copy your code.

- Go to `Files > New > Project..`
- Select `sbt`

[image: new project]

- And add Name and Location.
- Copy your files in `yourProject/src/main/scala`
- Now your HelloWorld should like this:

[image: run hello]

- Right click on the green Arrow, and run the program.
- This will create automatically a Start configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I setup a quick hello world app in IntelliJ in the following manner

1. Execute `sbt new scala/scala-seed.g8` to get the correct project structure
2. Point IntelliJ to the newly created hello world via `File | Open`
3. When prompted for `Import Project from sbt` settings I select `Use sbt shell` for both `imports` and `builds`, so I get the same build behaviour in IntelliJ and system terminal.
4. Finally I right-click on `Hello.scala` and `Run 'Hello'` to automatically setup run configuration.

Comment: My mistake was that I had `class  example extends App` instead of `object example extends App`.  I guess that without a main class, I didn't get an automatic configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You can add Scala under your existing project as following.

Under project set up (command + ;) -> global libraries -> + -> Scala SDK
[image]